# MediaWiki : storing in external databases

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am finding out a way to store the data in external databases rather than the default mediawiki database. As far as reading part is concerned, I am using the ExternalData extension as follows.

```
 {{#get_db_data:
  db=journal-db
  |from=journals
  |where= JQ2 > 9
  |data=rank=Rank,name=Name,rating=Rating,jq2=JQ2
 }}
```

This works perfectly fine. I get the results from the external database in variables data, name, rating, jq2. Now can anyone help me with how to store the data in external database, since there is not much documentation available for it? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you want to store SMW triplets separately from the rest of the MediaWiki DB? If that's what you are asking, check out: http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Using_SPARQL_and_RDF_stores

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the new https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo